# Print inside iFrame Media Query

Tags: css, iframe, media-queries

I have this web page that open up an iFrame, with a  width of 900px. There is a print button in the iFrame that calls `window.print()` and it only prints a certain div in the iFrame. I am using media queries to do this. In my `print.css` I have these 2 queries

```
@media print {
    /*
     * This is the normal print when I want to print the web page,
     * it hides the menu and other unnecessary information
     * so that it won't print
     */
}

@media print and (max-width: 900px) {
    /*
     * here I set the body's visible to hidden,
     * and only display the div that I want to print
     */
}
```

The problem is that the second media query is being applied when I just want to print regularly, and because the second media query hide the body I get a blank page. It works fine in the iFrame. If I where to remove the second media query I can print fine normally, but when I print form the iFrame it prints all these necessary background stuff from the parent window. If I where to combine the two, I would have to add "special" selector for everything on the web page that I want to print otherwise when I get a blank page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `max-width` to `min-width`